# How to update php without breaking dependencies [Lamp]

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

Im currently running PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 on ubuntu 14.04
I want to update to php 7.1.10 but im not sure how to do it.
Im also running mysql and phpmyadmin which I dont want to break.
Are there important things to keep in mind so everything keeps working? 
When updating things im always scared to break dependencies is this a realistic fear or shouldn't I worry about it?

Comment: Yes, it's a realistic fear. Once you move away from the versions in the 14.04 repositories, you will find support much harder to find. Most support will start with "Well, revert to stock 14.04 and see if it still happens." FYI: The next LTS, 18.04, is only six months away and will include php 7.1 (or even newer)

Comment: If you truly need to update PHP to 7.1.10 consider cloning the system to a test environment (it sounds like your current setup is mission critical) then you can fully test to insure that you haven't broken anything and also test possible solutions to any unintended consequences without risking a mission critical setup.  The [changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.1.10) may help you determine if you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure everything goes fine then you could use [phpfarm](https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm)

I once did that for a specific application and after setting up php 7.0.0, i encountered some errors with phpmyadmin that were not happening in php5

When it comes to extensive testing of a complex application, it may also prove useful to have both versions available at different ports/hosts. This [tutorial](https://blog.cadena-it.com/linux-tips-how-to/phpfarm-how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-php-on-the-same-computer/) describes a way to do that.

Comment: You encountered errors when using phpfarm? Why do you advice it than?

Comment: phpfarm did its job very well. But phpmyadmin was not running well with php 7.0.0